# Combinatorial proof of this identity: $ \sum_{k=0}^m \left(\!\!\binom{n}k\!\!\right) = \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}m\!\!\right), n\geq0$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, multisets

> I'm trying to give a combinatorial proof of this identity:
> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^m \left(\!\!\binom{n}k\!\!\right) = \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}m\!\!\right), n\geq0
> $$

I think the right-hand side could be interpreted as to cast k votes for elements from the set of candidates $[n+1] = {1, 2, 3, . . . , n+1} $ separately, but I'm having difficulty making a consistent argument to show two sides of the equation are equivalent (instead of using definitions to give a mathematical derivation). Thanks for the help!

> **Note:** $\displaystyle\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)$ stands for [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: Unless the double parenthesis means something other than binomial coefficients, I don't see how this identity is true.

Comment: @Alan Abraham That's multiset, I'm not sure how to directly type that